# AD group name edited, but SQL Server still shows old name

Tags: active-directory, sql-server

My databases in SQL Server are given access via an AD Group. The Net Admins changed the group name, but SQL Server still shows the old name.

How can I find out what the new AD Group name is? Also, how can I update so SQL Server reflects the new name?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is SQL Server just uses the initial name of the Active Directory group when the Group is stored in the SQL Server instance. In the background SQL Server actually stores the SID of the Windows Authenticated Active Directory group. Any changes to the Group's name on Active Directory level are not reflected in  the SQL Server instance, because it is not really relevant for the authentication, as the SQL Server instance used the stored SID.

## Register Windows AD Group as SQL Server Login

```
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\OLD_NAME] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
```

## Query SQL Server Instance (AD) Groups

The registered Windows Groups that act as "SQL Server Logins" on a SQL Server instance can be queried with:

```
SELECT  ssp.name, 
        ssp.sid, 
        ssp.type, 
        ssp.type_desc  
FROM    sys.server_principals AS ssp 
WHERE   ssp.type = 'G'
GO
```

The statement will return something like this:

> ```
> +-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+
> |      name       |                            sid                             | type |   type_desc   |
> +-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+
> | DOMAIN\OLD_NAME | 0x010500000000000515000000EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFF0000 | G    | WINDOWS_GROUP |
> +-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+
> ```

## Correcting SQL Server Login Name

Changing the name to the correct name can be achieved with the following statement:

```
ALTER LOGIN [DOMAIN\OLD_NAME] WITH NAME = [DOMAIN\NEW_NAME]
GO
```

> Name : The new name of the login that is being renamed. **If this is a Windows login, the SID of the Windows principal corresponding to the new name must match the SID associated with the login in SQL Server.**

<sup>***Reference:** [ALTER LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

Comment: Nice!! Is there a way to query the AD to find out the name given the SID from SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the annoyances of SQL server. Tell your AD admins that you are using X security group in SQL and ask them to tell you what its new name is. They changed it - they should know. If they don't know, then kick up a stink with your boss. They should have some kind of job ticket for making changes like that.

However, this points to a best-practice thing to do for SQL server. What you should do is ensure that AD groups are created *specifically* for database access.

For example, if you have users with DBO, Writer and Reader roles for a specific database, then you'd have AD groups that are named something like SQL-[DBName]-DBO, SQL-[DBName]-Writer, SQL-[DBName]-Reader - it should include whatever the actual database name is so you know which one the group is linked to. And obviously the role being assigned to it.

The DBAs will ideally be the only people permitted to approve changes to the group name or that the specific groups be created/deleted.

Then if you have existing groups of users, like teams or departments, those groups can be nested *inside* the DB access groups. That way, any user groups can be named whenever some boss decides to change the department name, but the DB access group is completely unaffected.

In fact, that's what I suggest you do now. Ask your AD admins to create one or more groups that match the user roles in the affected database. Once that's done, they should "nest" the group they renamed inside the appropriate new DB group (like the "Readers", if that's the role they had). Once the new dedicated database groups are ready, add them in SQL Management Studio under the database Security tab (I'm assuming it's not a server-wide permission, but it's the same principle there too), and assign the appropriate role.

You could just directly add the original group back by its new name and assign the role (and delete the old one), but who knows when it will happen again? Creating these DB-specific groups now will make these problems much less likely. Also, it can reduce work for you if they want to grant other people/teams the same access to the same database.